# Why does this Scala 3 macros reference example of HOAS fail with "Type must be fully defined" error?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

I'm new to scala 3 macros, and am trying to learn my way around them. In trying to learn how to use expression pattern matching, I tried to plug in this example from the reference [1]:

```
'{ ((x: Int) => x + 1).apply(2) } match
  case '{ ((y: Int) => $f(y)).apply($z: Int) } =>
    // f may contain references to `x` (replaced by `$y`)
    // f = (y: Expr[Int]) => '{ $y + 1 }
    f(z) // generates '{ 2 + 1 }
```

My attempt to exercise this leads to a compile failure. Of course, to run this, one needs an appropriate context, with quotes, etc. I have tried to create a 'minimal' additional scaffolding to test this. I have wrapped this as follows.

In `ExprMatchingPlayground.scala`:

```
package macrotest
import scala.quoted.*

object ExprMatchingPlayground {

  inline def foo(whatever: Any): Any = ${scrutinize('whatever)}

  def scrutinize[T](e: Expr[T])(using qctx: Quotes): Expr[T] = {
    import qctx.reflect.*
    // literal copy-paste of reference example
    '{ ((x: Int) => x + 1).apply(2) } match
      case '{ ((y: Int) => $f(y)).apply($z: Int) } =>
        // f may contain references to `x` (replaced by `$y`)
        // f = (y: Expr[Int]) => '{ $y + 1 }
        f(z) // generates '{ 2 + 1 }
    
    e // no-op returns original e
  }
}
```

and a basic use, at `ExprMatchingDemo.scala`

```
package macrotest

object ExprMatchingDemo extends App {
  ExprMatchingPlayground.foo(3 + 4 * 2) // this specific expression doesn't matter
}
```

My scala version is 3.3.1
In sbt, I've expanded my compile options as

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-Xcheck-macros",
  "-feature",
  "-explain"
)
```

On compile, I get the following output:

```
[error] -- Error: /Users/aaron/toolbox/toolbox/src/main/scala/toolbox/macros/tasty/ExprMatchingPlayground.scala:12:28
[error] 12 |      case '{ ((y: Int) => $f(y)).apply($z: Int) } =>
[error]    |                            ^
[error]    |                 Type must be fully defined.
[error]    |                 Consider annotating the splice using a type ascription:
[error]    |                   ($<none>(y): XYZ).
[error] -- [E006] Not Found Error: /Users/aaron/toolbox/toolbox/src/main/scala/toolbox/macros/tasty/ExprMatchingPlayground.scala:15:8
[error] 15 |        f(z) // generates '{ 2 + 1 }
[error]    |        ^
[error]    |        Not found: f
[error]    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[error]    | Explanation (enabled by `-explain`)
[error]    |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[error]    | The identifier for `f` is not bound, that is,
[error]    | no declaration for this identifier can be found.
[error]    | That can happen, for example, if `f` or its declaration has either been
[error]    | misspelt or if an import is missing.
[error]     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[error] Explanation
[error] ===========
[error] The identifier for `f` is not bound, that is,
[error] no declaration for this identifier can be found.
[error] That can happen, for example, if `f` or its declaration has either been
[error] misspelt or if an import is missing.
[error] -- [E006] Not Found Error: /Users/aaron/toolbox/toolbox/src/main/scala/toolbox/macros/tasty/ExprMatchingPlayground.scala:15:10
[error] 15 |        f(z) // generates '{ 2 + 1 }
[error]    |          ^
[error]    |          Not found: z
[error]    |----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[error]    | Explanation (enabled by `-explain`)
[error]    |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[error]    | The identifier for `z` is not bound, that is,
[error]    | no declaration for this identifier can be found.
[error]    | That can happen, for example, if `z` or its declaration has either been
[error]    | misspelt or if an import is missing.
[error]     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[error] Explanation
[error] ===========
[error] The identifier for `z` is not bound, that is,
[error] no declaration for this identifier can be found.
[error] That can happen, for example, if `z` or its declaration has either been
[error] misspelt or if an import is missing.
```

Is this reference example no longer good, or do I need to have something else specific in the surrounding wrapper to make it work?
Any comments, suggestions, references, context etc which aren't full answers are still greatly appreciated.

#### what I've tried

In addition to the specific macro definition and attempted use in the code snippets above, I have also tried variations:

- removing the import of `qctx.reflect.*` which I think isn't important here?
- a version of `scrutinize` which doesn't receive an expression argument, and returns a canned expression `'{2}` (and has return type `Expr[Int]`)
- in my sbt, I have tried setting the scalaVersion to `"3.2.0'`, `"3.1.0"`, and `"3.0.0"`, on the off-chance that this functionality worked in the past and was somehow withdrawn without the docs being appropriately updated -- however, though the specific error message changes, and in some cases *other* sections of my project also break, some version of the "Type must be fully defined" and "Not found: f" in this short example remain.
- Though I think this should not be necessary (since I'm using a copy-pasted reference example!), I have tried adding annotations at various points. However, even if I explicitly say

```
      case '{ ((y: Int) => (($f): Int => Int)(y)).apply($z: Int)} =>
        // f may contain references to `x` (replaced by `$y`)
        // f = (y: Expr[Int]) => '{ $y + 1 }
        f(z) // generates '{ 2 + 1 }
```

... I get an error saying that `f does not take parameters`. Of course, `f` *isn't* really a function -- it's this HOAS form that represents the body. So what should its type annotation be?

#### what I'm expecting

Given that this is an example copy-pasted from the scala 3 reference site, I expected:

a. the compile step should run without errors and

b. it should generate the code present in the comment in that reference example (and this could be verified by e.g. binding the result and printing with `println(s"generated = ${generated.asTerm.show(using Printer.TreeCode)}")`)

However, given my unfamiliarity with scala 3 macros, I'm guessing there may be something basic I'm missing in the context surrounding the pattern-matching.

[1] https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html#hoas-patterns-1

Comment: I tried to play a bit with this example - pass `[T: Type]` there, replace `(e: Any)` with `[T](e: T)`... and got the exactly same error. I was using pattern-patching on expressions, even pattern-matching on functions, and there was no such issue. I suspect that this particular example might have come from some earlier version of macros tutorials, and wasn't checked for regressions. E.g. if you change the match to `case '{ ((y: Int) => ${f}(y)).apply(${z}: Int) } =>` - which is exactly the same thing - then the compiler with crash. IMHO it's a bug and I would report it on Dotty's GH.

Comment: I've submitted a bug on GHhttps://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/19342

Comment: Also, I have been able to alter the example enough to get it to compile, but not to behave as intended. Adding an annotation in the pattern `case '{ ((y: Int) => $f(y): Int).apply($z: Int) }` is enough for `f` to be available, but it has type `Expr[Int => Int]` rather than `Expr[Int] => Expr[Int]`, which means it cannot be used to yield an expression in which only `y` has been replaced with some value.

Comment: Well, you cannot have patterns returning `Expr[A] => Expr[B]` - you can create such a function, but pattern matching on expressions can only extract values of type `Expr[Something]` just like unquoting can only insert `Expr`s there. If you want to have `Expr[X] => Expr[Y]` you have to write something like `(x: Expr[X]) => { x match { case pattern => extractedY } }` manually.

Comment: Oh, and you can easily turn `aToB: Expr[A => B]` into `Expr[A] => Expr[B]`: `(a: Expr[A]) => '{ ${aToB}(${a}) }` - this would just manually apply argument to the lambda.